# Graph theory - computing a probability

Tags: probability, graph-theory

I am trying to compute the following probability:

Let's say we have three nodes i, j , and k.

We know one node is of type H (high) and the two others of type L (low).

We know that we have a line directed graph: node(i) -- node(j) -- node(k).

The interaction between a node of type H and a node of type L (when H points at L) is called {HL} (similarly interaction between L and H is {LH}, between L and L is {LL}). For example node i can be of type H and can be placed on the extreme left of the line graph.

Over all we have 4 possible interactions (because we have 2 edges in this directed graph).

**If we don't know where H (possibly node i, j or k) is placed, what is the probability of the interaction of type {HL}, that is when node i or j or k of type H points at other node(s) ?**

(We know that if node of type H is on the extreme left or right then the frequency of the interaction is 1/4, if the node of type H is in the middle the frequency of interaction is 2/4).

Thank you in advance,

Comment: I think this isn't clear enough. If node of type $H$ is in the left ( or right, it doesn't matter) then the probability of an edge $\{HL\}$ appearing is $1/2$ (assuming all edge directions are equiprobable), but you say it is $1/4$, could you explain it further, please?

Comment: Thanks for replying. This is directed graph, if H is on the left then the probability of the "interaction" between her and a node of type L is 1/4. If she is on the left, the she would only interact with the central node; we call this interaction {HL}. Similarly the central node interacts with H (on her left) and L (on her right); giving interaction (directed edge from central node to the 2 nodes at the extremes) {LH} and {LL}. The node on the right, can only be of type L, thus interaction {LL} occurs. Interaction here means existence of a directed edge from i to j.

Comment: All in all we have 4 possible interactions. If we know where H is (we suppose it is on the left, there are 2 other possibilities) then we know that the frequency of interaction {HL} is just 1 over 4 possible interaction. The question is what is the probability of of interaction if we don't know which node is H? Thank you

Comment: @CarlosLaguillo

Comment: Sorry I am new and not sure how to mention names @carlos

Comment: I'm still missunderstanding this, shuoldn't always appear the 2 edges? If so, you have 4 possibilities, namely:
H->L->L, H->L<-L, H<-L<-L and H<-L->L so the probability of an edge H->L appearing is $1/2$

Comment: sorry my formulation is misleading and wrong, the interpretation in my head made me give misleading description of the graph. It is like there is an "edge" between i and j allowing communication (a phone call). But if i is of type H (high charisma) and j is type L (low charisma), then i doesn't influence j the same way j influences i (j will be more influenced by j) - this is as if the edges had different capacities ({HL} and {LH}. The line graph in this case is wrong, I am sorry. It is more like a graph with three nodes, i, j, and k such that i->j and j->i and j->k and k->j. @carlos

Comment: @CarlosLaguillo

Answer (score 1):

Your graph has the adjacency matrix $A$, where

$A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 0&1&0\\ 1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{array}\right]$

Now the probability of the interaction $HL$ is
$P(HL|HLL)+P(HL|LHL)+P(HL|LLH)=1/4+2/4+1/4=1$, i.e. for sure you get an interaction $HL$, no matter how the nodes are labeled as you stated.